enable labels documents policy
I am trying to apply label to document content type in SharePoint Online. Basically, what I need to is to enable labels on documents using Information management policy settings. The problem is I can do this manually, but I cannot find a way to do this programmatically. Any idea how do do this?
I do expect to find the documentation for this. I can use PnP or CSOM, it depends on what documentation I find.

SharePoint sensitivity labels cannot be associated with content types. They are meant to be assigned to individual documents or folders, but not entire content types.
A single label for an entire content type would not allow for the fact that documents within a content type can have varying levels of sensitivity.
You can set a default label for a specific SharePoint location (library or site), which the user can then override manually.

Is not a  sensitive label, is a policy label. Can be associated with a content type, but manually. I see no documentation about how to do this programmatically.  Even more, I want to add {Version} as label, but this is working only on attached content types.
